# How to use Imagick to create pdf's thumbnail

Tags: imagick

I want to create a caption of a pdf file that a user uploads on my site. So I installed Imagick, is there any tutorial or any best practise to know how to create a image thumbnail from this pdf ?

By the way, I tried :

```
        $img = new Imagick($_url);
        $img->setiteratorindex(0);
        $img->setCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_LZW);
        $img->setCompressionQuality(90);
```

And I must have an installation problem because the object Imagick is not recognized, how do I configure ImageMagick to make it fit with my php configuration ?

Comment: I belive you need to enable Imagick in the php.info file.

Answer (score -1):

Check phpinfo() if imagick is installed.

Otherwise install with apt-get install php5-imagick (for Linux).

You can find some good tutorials on [Mikko’s blog](http://valokuva.org/?p=7)